# What does "cram" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "cram" mean in this sentence?

> It's not that they're **cramming** for some project. It's that long-term
>   procrastination has made them feel like a spectator, at times, in
>   their own lives

Source link : https://www.ted.com/talks/tim_urban_inside_the_mind_of_a_master_procrastinator/transcript#t-555311

Hope someone could explain it to me.

Answer (score 2):

**cramming** is a colloquial word for urgent studying, such as immediately before an exam.  Different countries and schools use different words for this.

It follows "to cram" which is to put more into a container than usual.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramming_(education)

Comment: That what I have thought. Thank you ^_^